# Excel conditional formatting based on multiple cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, genetics

I am having trouble coming up with a usable conditional formatting formula in Excel to highlight patterns.

[image: Starting Sample Data]

```
Phase   Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6 Sample7 Sample8
{0-}    lm  ll  lm  lm  ll  lm  ll  lm
{0-}    lm  ll  lm  lm  ll  lm  ll  lm
{1-}    lm  ll  ll  lm  lm  ll  lm  ll
{0-}    lm  ll  lm  ll  ll  lm  ll  lm
{1-}    lm  ll  ll  lm  lm  ll  lm  ll
{1-}    lm  ll  ll  lm  lm  ll  lm  ll
{0-}    lm  ll  lm  ll  ll  lm  ll  lm
{1-}    lm  ll  ll  lm  lm  ll  lm  ll
{1-}    lm  ll  ll  lm  lm  ll  lm  ll
```

(tsv format)

Given the sample above, the formatting I want to do, in English is:

"If, for every row in the spreadsheet, the cell in column A="{0-}", highlight any cell in the same row that contains "lm", else, highlight any cell containing "ll" "

The desired outut would look something like this

[image]

PS: For some background (that isn't quite relevant for the question here, but is more for anyone in the future who might google search for a similar question): I am evaluating a genetic map from an outcrossing population based on the output of the program JoinMap. These calls are coded based based on the underlying genotype and the calculated phase is given in the first column.  I am, in essence, attempting to re-create the JoinMap output in the program itself  but in Excel, so it can be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple actually. What follows is based on your table, cells' adresse and so on...

---

**0 - Create a table one is going to use for a forthcoming VLOOKUP function. Say, in cells `A14:B15`, write**

```
      A     B
14    lm    {0-}
15    ll    {1-}
```

---

**1 - Select the cells `B2:I10`**

---

**2 - Click Conditional formatting > New Rule…**

[image]

---

**3 - In the New Formatting Rule window, select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format.***

[image]

---

In the *"Enter your formula"* box above, copy paste this line of code

`=$A2=VLOOKUP(B2,$A$14:$B$15,2,FALSE)`

Do not forget to *"choose the format"*. And press OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please select ColumnsA:I and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(AND($A1="{0-}",A1="lm"),AND($A1<>"{0-}",A1="ll"))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.